# Can we migrate the list items and documents only from on-premises to online

Tags: sharepoint-online, migration, content-migration

Previously we have migrated a site collection from on-perm 2013 to online. and we start using the migrated online site, but this online site have 10 sub-sites, which we have been using the on-premises versions, since they contain custom solution not support inside SharePoint online. now i want to migrate the data-only from on-premises to online? so is this possible using powershell? we have a migration tool but this migration tool only allow us to migrate a whole site, but in our case we have all the settings and the site collection already migrated, and we only want to migrate Data including list items and documents, without any other components. so can anyone advice on the available approaches we can follow?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure which migration tool you are using - but in general all migration tools like **ShareGate**, **Metalogix**, **Microsoft Migration tool** provides two ways of migration,

1. Migrate site object with copy structure which will do the as-is migration, a complete replica of the source to target except for the custom solution.
2. Migrate only content which will allow us to do the granular level migration like right from individual list item to the whole set of libraries, just need to configure the tool.

Then coming to your subsite approaches after migration in SharePoint online, as we know Microsoft has introduced the hub site architecture where we can drastically eliminate the sub-site which we say nested level architecture which is very complicated to manage in the long run. Now, you may think about each subsite to the individual site and associated them into a hub site and through the megamenu, you can manage them very efficiently and easily.

With that being said, still, we can go ahead and create the subsite in SharePoint online - if you have a business requirement to have the same architecture as your source environment ie. SharePoint 2013 - you can continue to use that, there won't be any issues. :-)

Comment: i am using AvePoint Fly tool, and it does not provide a way to migrate the data (list items and documents) only.

Comment: Ohh.. you can try the Microsoft migration tool, it is free no license needed.

Comment: have you tried this tool recently? as i tried it couple of months ago, and it only supported migrating documents , it does not support list items.. not sure if things have changed or not..

Comment: Sharegate is the best so far, in my opinion. The license is quite affordable too. Microsoft's SharePoint Migration Tool works too, with some limitations if you want to be "creative" in your migration plan.